# Android Thread.name

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-threads

Я работаю с потоками в своем проекте. Среди прочих потоков, в двух разных классах создается две `HandlerThread` таким вот образом:

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceThread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

Дальше они стартуются: `thread.start();`, и я использую их луперы.
И только что я обнаружил, что они создаются с абсолютно одинаковыми именами (первый параметр в конструкторе - имя).
Мой вопрос состоит в том, могут ли быть проблемы из за того, что у потоков одинаковые имена? Являются ли имена какими-то идентификаторами для потоков?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не будет проблем.

При создании нового `HandlerThread` вызывается конструктор:

```
    public HandlerThread(String name, int priority) {
        super(name);
        mPriority = priority;
    }
```

Идем вглубь и видим

```
    if (threadName == null) {
       this.name = "Thread-" + id;
    } else {
        this.name = threadName
    }
```

Что и есть практическим подтверждением написанного в [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> Каждый поток имеет имя в целях идентификации. Более чем один поток может иметь такое же имя . Если имя не указано , когда создается поток, новое имя генерируется для него.

Answer (score 4):

Нет, имена в `thread` не имеют никакого значения кроме удобства тестирования и логирования. 
Уникальным идентификатором `thread` будет `pid`.

Answer (score 4):

Из [оффдока](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

> Every thread has a name for identification purposes. More than one thread may have the same name. If a name is not specified when a thread is created, a new name is generated for it.

По идее про проблемы ничего не сказано, значит это нормально